# Android resize any dimension of images to a specific dimension size and save all the images to sdcard folder

Tags: android, image, resize, image-resizing

Let's say i have some images in my sdcard but they have different dimesions like 1920*1080, 2500*1400, 600*400 etc.

now i want to resize all of them to a specific dimension( 820*480) without loosing quality and keep aspect ratio. After resizing down/up i want to fill the blank space of my desired dimension with black color.

how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bitmap bFrom = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("filename");
    final int w = bFrom.getWidth();
    final int h = bFrom.getHeight();
    final int destW = 820;
    final int destH = 480;

    if ((w > 0) && (h > 0)) {
        Bitmap bTo = Bitmap.createBitmap(destW, destH, bFrom.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bTo); // Canvas to draw
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK); // Clear the canvas
        float scale = Math.min((float) destW / w, (float) destH / h); // calculate the scale
        float scaledW = w * scale;
        float scaledH = h * scale;
        RectF destRect = new RectF((destW - scaledW) * 0.5f, (destH - scaledH) * 0.5f, (destW + scaledW) * 0.5f, (destH + scaledH) * 0.5f);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bFrom, null, destRect, null); // draw with scale;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output_filename");
            try {
                bTo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos); // save to file as png (lossless)
            } finally {
                bTo.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // handle IOException 
        }
    }
```